# implementation of 'std::cmp::PartialEq' is not general enough

Tags: rust, mocking, traits

I am trying to use [mockiato](https://crates.io/crates/mockiato) to mock a function that accepts an `Option` of my struct `A` but am receiving the following error.

```
error: implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` is not general enough
   --> src\main.rs:45:14
    |
45  |               .expect_do_feature(|arg| arg.partial_eq(Some(&cfg)))
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` is not general enough
    |
    = note: `std::cmp::PartialEq<std::option::Option<&'1 A>>` would have to be implemented for the type `std::option::Option<&A>`, for any lifetime `'1`...
    = note: ...but `std::cmp::PartialEq` is actually implemented for the type `std::option::Option<&'2 A>`, for some specific lifetime `'2`
```

I would've thought the `#[derive(PartialEq)]` on the `struct A` would generate what was needed, but it looks like it doesn't quite do the full job. How do I implement what the compiler is telling me to do?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[cfg(test)]
use mockiato::mockable;

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct A {
    pub data: HashMap<String, i32>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        A {
            data: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}

pub struct B;

#[cfg_attr(test, mockable)]
pub trait ProvidesFeature {
    fn do_feature(&self, config: Option<&A>) -> Option<Vec<i32>>;
}

impl B {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        B {}
    }

    pub fn do_feature(&self, config: Option<&A>) -> Option<Vec<i32>> {
        Some(vec!())
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_mocking() {
        let mut feature_mock = ProvidesFeatureMock::new();
        feature_mock
            .expect_do_feature(|arg| arg.partial_eq(None))
            .times(1..)
            .returns(Some(vec!()));
        assert_eq!(vec![0; 0], feature_mock.do_feature(None).unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

In order to compile, I used `mockiato = "0.9.5"` in `Cargo.toml`. Don't forget to run this with `cargo test` if you attempt to reproduce.

Comment: I think from deriving you only get a `PartialEq` for references, that have the same lifetime. If like here you need it for references of different lifetimes, you need higher-ranked trait bounds: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer Which bound are you suggesting can be made higher ranked? There are no required trait bounds on a `PartialEq` impl, so it's already as general as it can be.

Comment: I think this is a limitation in mockiato itself. I would report an issue on the mockiato github and see if one of the maintainers can help - this is quite a gnarly error for quite a simple setup, so I would hope they can offer some guidance, given their knowledge of the internals.

Comment: After checking the existing issues on github I think [this issue](https://github.com/mockiato/mockiato/issues/117) is already known. Unfortunately, the last updates to the project are 6 months ago, so I don't know if there'll be a solution anytime soon.